# trying to add rows and cells to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been successful in adding rows and cells to a table when the content of each cell is a text input. But when I try to add custom text (or a hyperlink) I do not get any result. Here is my code:

```
if (bb == "link") {

            var newRow = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(thisTable);

            var newLinkCell = $("<td></td>").appendTo(newRow);

            var hInput = $("<span>" + l + "</span>").appendTo(newLinkCell);

        }
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE:**

This is the relevant code. A fiddle of the entire problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/N8sW2/1/

My problem deals with the "Link to Page" button. Please help.

Comment: I'm not seeing an 'add link' button. Did you mean 'link to page'?

Comment: @alpacalipsnao--yes, sorry about that. see the edits =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thisTable = $(this).siblings("table");
```

This line will find no elements because your add button has no siblings which are tables.

Comment: @JamesMontagne--I don't understand. The `addLink` button has a sibling  table called `hintBox`

Comment: Yes it does, but the `addLink` button does not call this code.  The `set` button does.  The set button has no sibling which is a table.   `$("#linkmodal").find("input[type = 'button']").setLink();`